# Easing doesn't work. It waits the duration and runs the animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I want to use jquery animate and easing and used to do it and see it working but right now I'm facing a new problem. It looks like it doesn't take my configuration in consideration.

I'm calling jquery.3.4.1 and jquery.easing.min.js via CDN. All my code is working great, no error whatsoever. I've tried jquery ui and it's the same. The final result of my animation is that when the mouse leaves, it waits the time of duration (200, 3000, whatever) and then animates the marginLeft kinda fast. It's like it doesn't get the duration in consideration.

```
$('#sliderContent > #nav').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $('.slide-background.cover.present > .slide-background-content').animate({
                      marginLeft: '+'+$('#nav').outerWidth(true)+'px'
                }, 200 );
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $('.slide-background.cover.present > .slide-background-content').animate({
                    marginLeft: '0px'
                }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
            }

        });
```

**EDIT :** The problem was actually from the CSS. I found out that my DIv with the class `.slide-background.cover.present > .slide-background-content` had a transition effect with the ease set as ease-out.

Comment: The properties being animated should be numeric - the construction of the 'px' string is not required. If that does not solve it then tt might help to make a cut-down version of your code and post it here as a working snippet or as fiddle so we can observe the issue first hand. Right now there is not enough information in your post to provide a useful response..

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the numeric values. That didn't solve it, I'll do a jsfiddle then

Comment: My fiddle is working great.. https://jsfiddle.net/ed209qut/ Is there something that could impeach animation and/or easing to work ? I don't get any console error and I'm loading the exact same libraries plus some other like bootstrap, fontawesome, jsvideo, nothing too specials.

Comment: Good work on the fiddle - now we know the issue is caused by something in your environment so we made a big step forward. I would try removing those other libs one by on until the issue is cleared then add back in to confirm the issue and investigate from there.

Comment: I just found out what it was. It was a CSS animation with an easing set on ease-out that blocked everything. Good to know CSS is stronger. Thanks !